# Modelagem de Banco

Tags: banco-de-dados, modelagem

Estou tentando fazer a modelagem de um banco para um Bolão simples para os jogos da Copa do Mundo. Seria dessa maneira mesmo?

[image: DER]

A ideia é que a pessoa possa se cadastrar e fazer palpites para cada partida informando um vencedor ou se terá um empate.

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 1):

Sem saber o que precisa fazer em detalhes não dá para dizer se está bom ou correto. Posso especular em cima do que é o minimamente óbvio sobre o domínio abordado.

Não sei o que a tabela `Partida_has_Selecao` faz, eu acho que que ela está a mais aí.

A tabela `Partida` deveria ter o `id` das duas seleções e não os nomes. E o resultado deveria ser dividido em duas colunas com o placar de cada time. A não ser que só precise saber quem foi o vencedor ou se deu empate o que um simples valor numérico ou enumeração com 3 estados bastaria. Não imagino porque precise ser um `VARCHAR(45)`.

Na tabela `Aposta` eu colocaria um `Id` como chave primária, mas é o meu gosto dentro da minha experiência. Não entendi para que serve a terceira coluna. E o padrão do palpite deveria seguir o padrão do resultado de `Partida`. No `Status` um booleano já bastaria.

Dá para sofisticar mais, mas depende do que a aplicação deseja fazer.

Comment: Maniero, obrigado pela ajuda. Já me esclareceu bastante coisa.

Como eu posso passar dois IDs da mesma tabela para outra? Sobre o resultado, o que me interessa seria apenas o nome do vencedor ou se deu empate. Poderia deixar um simples varchar(3)? 
Na tabela Aposta, concordo com você em relação a colocar um id para cada Aposta. A coluna Status seria para saber se o apostador chegou a fazer o "pagamento" da aposta (Pago ou Pendente)

Comment: Então realmente precisa muito mais do que você fez sobre o valor das apostas, de qualquer forma me parece que um tipo booleano é suficiente.  O vencedor pode ser um numérico simples, já que só há 3 possibilidades. `VARCHAR` é para descrições, não é o caso. Não entendi sobre os `ID`s.